# Kubernetes not able to connect to pod using service IP

Tags: kubernetes

I am following below document to create the service. this pod is running on both nodes.  when I make a request using master node IP, not getting any response.

```
curl http://192.168.15.101:30534
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/

```
> # kubectl cluster-info Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.15.101:6443 KubeDNS is running at
> https://192.168.15.101:6443/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-
```

system/services/kube-dns

Here is my routes

```
# ip r
default via 192.168.15.1 dev eth1
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15  metric 100
10.244.0.0/24 dev cni0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.244.0.1
10.244.0.0/16 dev flannel.1
10.244.0.0/14 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.244.0.1
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1003
192.168.15.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.15.101



 kubectl get pods --selector="run=load-balancer-example" --output=wide
NAME                           READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP            NODE
hello-world-3272482377-225z8   1/1       Running   1          18h       10.244.1.81   node-01
hello-world-3272482377-f6qqd   1/1       Running   1          18h       10.244.2.78   node-02
```

I check the iptables rules, NAT is set for cluster IP.

how can I troubleshoot this connection issue?

Thanks
-SR